# Powershell collect data from several files after a certain line, and append data to .xls

Tags: excel, powershell, parsing, split, scripting

I have several .txt files in a folder with the following consistent data pattern

```
(Row 1) top - 04:00:00 up 12 days, 13:34,  0 users,  load average: 0.99, 0.77, 0.71
(Row 2) Tasks: 450 total,   2 running, 448 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
(Row 3) %Cpu(s):  8.0 us,  3.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st  
(Row 4) KiB Mem : 65805780 total, 40321108 free,  8345456 used, 17139216 buff/cache
(Row 5) KiB Swap:  6291452 total,  6291452 free,        0 used. 55448280 avail Mem
(Row 6)
(Row 7) PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    10427 osiserv+  20   0 2756448 810852 335636 R 100.0  1.2   3720:13 spqr_rm_pmp+
```

The first 5 rows is server stat information, the 6th row is blank, and the 7th row contains the array file header (e.g. PID, USER, PR, NI, VIRT..etc..etc)

I would like to capture ALL the data below the header line which ALWAYS starts on **ROW 8** (for EACH file) and append to a single spreadsheet so that it appears as follows

[image]

Bare in mind the number of records below the ROW 7 header will vary (e.g. could be 5, 25, 100+c lines more) for each input file. Huge thanks again.

Update: I managed to ekes out some code but I'm having problems replacing ALL spaces with just a single comma. It either complains about the encoding, the delimeter or the out put just looks horrible with each column being shifted all over the place.

```
$ETL_FolderPath = "C:\cows\datafiles_in\test"
$ETL_DestinationFilePath = "C:\cows\datafiles_out\ETL-Files-TOP-DAPPS-Details.csv"
$lines = @()
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ETL_FolderPath -File
foreach ($file in $files) {
$fileLines = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 7
$fileLines = $fileLines -replace " ", ","
$fileLines = $fileLines | ForEach-Object {"$($file.Name),$($_) "}
$lines += $fileLines
}
$lines | Out-File -FilePath $ETL_DestinationFilePath -Encoding utf8 -Delimeter ","
```

Current Output: Notice it appears to replace spaces with random number of commas. I am looking for just a single comma between each spaced values.

[image]

Not sure where I goofed up in the delimeter part of the script.
I've even tried removed nulls as well but still some of the records appearing off kilter

```
# Remove Spaces
$fileLines = $fileLines -replace '\s+', ',' -replace '\0', ','
```

[image]

Comment: What does your script look like so far?

Comment: Thanks @Bill_Stewart I updated the query with the code I wrote. Challenge I am having is that it will not remove all the random spaces peppered in each row and simply replace with a single comma to save on headache. The script complains about encoding and delimeters. I get the desired output (all records -minus the junk header) but the values appear all over the place as opposed to neat comma delimited columns.

Comment: Observation. If you search for a single space and replace with a comma, multiple consecutive spaces will be replaced with multiple consecutive commas. Have you tried searching and replacing the combination of space and comma  (`,  `) with just a comma (`,`)?

Comment: Replace the spaces with nothings there are already commas in the file  : $fileLines = $fileLines -replace " ", ""

Comment: @bugdrown yeah, I tried filtering on variations of the theme around spaces and ending up with randomly indented records because of the random nulls. I had to put in filters for nulls, and blanks to address that

Comment: @jdweng I added a null filter with an indent command to address the mysterious and random nulls I was getting in the output. Not sure if it has something to do with encoding but I managed to address the two and it works. I wish there was a cleaner way to filter out exceptions but for now it will have to do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding these filters to get rid of random spaces, and nulls. Then added an "indent" to move the record in place of the null so it doesn't look goofy on the spreadsheet.

```
# Remove Spaces and Nulls
$fileLines = $fileLines -replace '\s+', ','
$fileLines = $fileLines -replace '\0', ','
$fileLines = $fileLines -replace '^,', ''
```

Might not be the cleanest but certainly works given the circumstance. If welcome any better suggestion to consolidate all the filters.